# apache Location really slower than Directory

Tags: apache2

On my apache server, I have a https virtualhost configured as:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/htdocs
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/localhost/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/include_bdd_access
        <Directory "/var/www/localhost/htdocs">
                Options -Indexes +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                <LimitExcept HEAD POST GET>
                        Require all denied
                </LimitExcept>
                Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
                Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
                Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
                Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff 
                AuthName "Global auth"
                Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/include_bdd_auth
        </Directory>
        <Location /webalizer>
                Options +Indexes -MultiViews -FollowSymLinks
        </Location>
[...]
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

webalizer/ just lists 10 dirs like:

```
site1.example.com
site2.example.com
...
```

All is fine, except that accessing to /webalizer dir is really very slow (exactly 16sec each time, no less, no more, confirmed by firefox web tools) and I don't understand why.

And I realized that if I change Location directive to Directory, it "only" takes about 2sec.

BUT, I have others  with same Options +Indexes that just take about 8sec to display 4 lines...

Is there any connection with the contents of these subdirectories?

Why is it much faster with Directory than with Location?

Is it then recommended to use Directory instead when possible?

Another thing I don't understand:

I can visit [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with:

```
$ curl https://username:password@www.example.com
```

But, impossible to access to /webalizer (with Location or Directory)

```
$ curl 'https://username:password@www.example.com/webalizer'
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.example.com/webalizer/">here</a>.</p>
```

Why?

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.example.com (/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/www.example.com-le-ssl.conf:1)
[...]
ServerRoot: "/usr/lib64/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: dir="/run/apache_ssl_mutex" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/apache2.pid"
Define: PHP
Define: AUTH_MYSQL
Define: LANGUAGE
Define: SSL
Define: STATUS
Define: SUEXEC
Define: MPM_ITK
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=72
Group: name="apache" id=72
```

Comment: Something is VERY wrong here. I typically see access times in the region of milliseconds. Without any details of the operating system, the method (network) by which you measured this, the version of Apache..... there's not much scope for guessing here but you could just run Apache with a single server and strace it.